# How do I write a function that handles different kinds of lists

Tags: python, function

I am trying to write a function that handles three kinds of lists:

1. if every element in the list is a number, return the sum of those numbers.
2. if every element in the list is a string, concatenate all the strings.
3. if the list contains mixed data types, transform every element to a string. Then, concatenate all strings.

This is what I have tried but I am stuck.

```
def func_op(any_list):
    if([x for x in any_list if x.isdigit()]):
        sum(x)
    elif(all(isinstance(item, str) for item in any_list)):
        ''.join(any_list)
    else:
        ''.join(list(map(str, any_list)))
```

The function should work for any of the three scenarios shown below.

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = ['apple,'orange']   
list3= ['apple','2',3, 'orange']
```

Right now, calling the function returns the following error message at the *sum* argument:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you think `if([x for x in any_list if x.isdigit()]):` is checking?

Comment: This code with ``func_op(list2)`` gives the error ``AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'``.

Comment: Do you consider ``'2'`` to be a number or a string?

Comment: ```if all(isinstance(i,int) for i in any_list):``` instead of ```if([x for x in any_list if x.isdigit()]):```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `all(isinstance(i,int) for i in any_list)` to check if all elements are integers.

```
def func_op(any_list):
    if all(isinstance(i,int) for i in any_list):
        return sum(any_list)
    elif all(isinstance(item, str) for item in any_list):
        return ''.join(any_list)
    else:
        return ''.join(list(map(str, any_list)))
```